# react native bar code reader is not working correctly?

Tags: react-native, expo

**Problem:**

I have created a react native application. There I am using expo-barcode-scanner. This is how my code is organized.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from "react-native";

import Dimensions from "Dimensions";

import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";

import { BarCodeScanner } from "expo-barcode-scanner";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      QrPress: false,
      hasCameraPermission: null, 
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionsAsync(); 
  }

  getPermissionsAsync = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === "granted" });
  };

  _onPress_QrScan() {
    this.setState({
      QrPress: true
    });
  }

  handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    this.setState({ QrPress: false, scanned: true, lastScannedUrl: data });
  };

  renderBarcodeReader() {
    const { hasCameraPermission, scanned } = this.state;

    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
    }
    if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    }
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "flex-end"
        }}
      >
        <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : this.handleBarCodeScanned}
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
        />

        {scanned && (
          <Button
            title={"Tap to Scan Again"}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ scanned: false })}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission, scanned, QrPress } = this.state;
    let marker = null;

    if (this.state.locationChosen) {
      marker = <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.focusedLocation} />;
    }
    return (
      <View style={{}}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled>
          <ScrollView>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                this._onPress_QrScan();
              }}
              activeOpacity={3}
            >
              <Text style={styles.viewDetails}>Scan QR</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {QrPress ? (
              <React.Fragment>{this.renderBarcodeReader()}</React.Fragment>
            ) : (
              null
            )}
          </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const DEVICE_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    top: 0,
    flex: 3
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 130
  },
  homeHeader: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    flex: 1
  },
  homeHeaderImage: {
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  homeHederText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontStyle: "normal",
    fontFamily: "sans-serif",
    letterSpacing: 0.81,
    color: "#000104",
    marginTop: "2%",
    marginLeft: "40%",
    marginRight: "3%"
  },
  hederContentContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: "30%",
    marginBottom: "10%"
  },
  qrCodeGeneraterContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },

});


export default Home;
```

But when I open the app with expo client on my android mobile. It is not rendering the barcode reader. It means It is not opening the camera to scan the QR. It just only shows a blank white background. I tried a lot to find out the solution to this problem. Unfortunately, I could not do anything with this issue. Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clean up your question by narrowing your code down to something that you can reasonably expect someone else on the internet to read and understand. There's so much there that someone would have to go through.

Comment: @tekknolagi Thank you. I updated the question with code reduction. The problem I have is it is not opening the camera to scan the QR.

Comment: Are you using a real device or an emulator?

Comment: @harisu I am using real device

Comment: @TharinduSandaruwan What exactly happens when you click on `Scan QR`

Comment: Looking at your code it seem it doesn't have anything to do with it. What version of expo sdk are you using?

Comment: @harisu SDK version is 35. When I click on it, It only shows a blank page in white.

Comment: Try clearing the app data and then perform a fresh installation of the app then try it out again.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot's of issue in your component. Please use the below code and update the style etc depend on your requirements.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Dimensions,
  Button,
} from "react-native";
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";

import { BarCodeScanner } from "expo-barcode-scanner";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      QrPress: false,
      hasCameraPermission: null, 
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionsAsync(); 
  }

  getPermissionsAsync = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === "granted" });
  };

  _onPress_QrScan = () => {
    this.setState({
      QrPress: true
    });
  }

  handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    this.setState({ QrPress: false, scanned: true, lastScannedUrl: data });
  };

  renderBarcodeReader = () => {
    const { hasCameraPermission, scanned } = this.state;

    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
    }
    if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    }
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "flex-end",
        }}
      >
        <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : this.handleBarCodeScanned}
          style={{ flex:1, ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}
        />

        {scanned && (
          <Button
            title={"Tap to Scan Again"}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ scanned: false })}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission, scanned, QrPress } = this.state;
    let marker = null;

    if (this.state.locationChosen) {
      marker = <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.focusedLocation} />;
    }
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled style={{flex:1}}> 
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}} >
            {QrPress ? (
              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                {this.renderBarcodeReader()}
              </View>
            ) : (
                <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
               <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={this._onPress_QrScan}
              activeOpacity={3}
            >
              <Text style={styles.viewDetails}>Scan QR</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
            )}
          </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const DEVICE_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    top: 0,
    flex: 3
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 130
  },
  homeHeader: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    flex: 1
  },
  homeHeaderImage: {
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  homeHederText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontStyle: "normal",
    fontFamily: "sans-serif",
    letterSpacing: 0.81,
    color: "#000104",
    marginTop: "2%",
    marginLeft: "40%",
    marginRight: "3%"
  },
  hederContentContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: "30%",
    marginBottom: "10%"
  },
  qrCodeGeneraterContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },

});


export default Home;
```